# HLS Preset Settings 240p, 360p, 480p, 720p and 1080p

Tags: encoding, transcoding, bitrate, hls

I am  trying to transcode mp4 videos into HLS using AWS transcoder. I see that there are only few presets available which are like 1M, 1.5M and the highest 2M. I am unable to get 240, 360 , 480,720p and 1080p

Could someone help me with different transcoder settings to create these presets? I don't understand most of the fields presented in the presets.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What fields do you specifically have questions about? Have you come across any reference material that you don't understand?